# Teradata REPLICATE function?

Tags: sql, teradata, replicate

I'm converting MS SQL Server codes to Teradata.
I found out that Teradata has no replicate function.
Below is the sample code

```
REPLICATE('0',2-LEN(CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS NVARCHAR)))
```

Is there an alternative function for replicate in Teradata?

Thanks

Comment: There's `LPAD`/`RPAD` which can be used similarily. But what is this code actually used for, what datatype is `COLUMN_NAME`?

Comment: **http://xyproblem.info/** You are not getting the right solution here.

Comment: P.s. I wouldn't keep @dnoeth waiting. I promise you this is not going to be the last time you will ask for his help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SUBSTR('00', 1, 2-CHARACTER_LENGTH(CAST(COLUMN_NAME AS VARCHAR(10)))
```

This will repeat the character `'0'` two minus the length of the column, which is effectively doing the same thing as `REPLICATE` in SQL Server.

Comment: This worked! I just added zeroes(just in case there are more needed). By the way, since there is no nvarchar in TD, is the VARCHAR(10) equivalent to it?

Comment: @user2331719 I'm not expert enough in Teradata to give you an exact answer, though `CHARACTER_LENGTH` should give you the number of characters regardless of the column size.  So just make sure the column is wide enough such that all information survives the cast.

Comment: Noted. Thanks again.

Comment: I believe VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET UNICODE would be the equivalent of nvarchar(10).  In many cases you are probably still fine with just VARCHAR(10)

Answer (score 3):

General equivalent would be:

```
select LPAD('0', needed_length, '0');
```

Comment: Much better answer. Thanks!